# Using Core Data in my Project

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to implement Core Data in my project to my project, to create entities, save data and retrieve data. I'm following these tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPe4TQc-iSE

My code for the moment:

```
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
```

I get this error:

> Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'managedObjectContext'

I did some search, and found that to have this in AppDelegate.swift, I have to tap 'Use Core Data' when I create a project, so how to do now when my project is already created ?

I think I miss persistentStoreCoordinator too and the other function to use Core Data.

Comment: Re-create the project :)

Comment: @Cristik I have a lot of parameters like using personal font

Comment: You can create a new project, check Core Data. See how AppDelegate is setup in that project. Copy paste a couple of functions and change the names were needed. It is a pain. Almost easier to re-create the project as @Cristik suggested. Drag the files from the old to the new. (you can also drag a storyboard into another project)

Comment: @RMenke So they're only differences on AppDelegate.swift when we check UseCoreData and they're not another files ?

Comment: @RMenke Looks work as well thanks

Comment: @Ben you would also need to add a datamodel file. (new file....) the name of this file is what goes in AppDel

Comment: If you want the apple boiler plate code, just google: "Add Core Data to an existing swift project". First result: http://craig24.com/2014/12/how-to-add-core-data-to-an-existing-swift-project-in-xcode/

Comment: @RMenke sure I already have a .xcdatamodeld file

Comment: @LaurentRivard Thanks I'm gonna look it :)

Comment: don't put this code in the app delegate, it doesn't belong there, create yourself a data manager or similar

Comment: @Wain So why xCode automatically put this code in AppDelegate ?

Comment: Don't rely on Apples templates to be good quality / practice. They are a simple starting point but they are by no means well designed...